# How to solve "Flutter iOS: Firebase Push Notification crashes app at Splash screen"?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, push-notification

Our Flutter iOS app is able to receive push notifications sent by Firebase properly. Once we click the notification, the splash screen shows up and then the app crashes instantly.

**Tested:** Used real device iPhone 7 Plus to test
**Async main():** We have made the main function asynchronously and inside we initialiazed-called the FCM code so that the notifications work in the main thread. We have also tried implementing the FCM notification part out of **main()** as async .
**On Android:** Notifications perfectly work and open the app's Homescreen on Android OS.
**Log/Run:** No issue detected so far .

A solution would be appreciated .

Comment: I have the same prob too. any solutions please ?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, anyone can suggest any solution?